# TV mentions Raspberry Pi 2 with OSMC is outputting 1366*768 on HDMI

Tags: hdmi

My TV - an Indian manufacturer called Micromax (http://www.snapdeal.com/product/micromax-50b5000fhd-50-inches-full/1405132060#bcrumbSearch:micromax%20tv)

when i connect the Raspberry Pi 2 flashed with OSMC to my HDMI port using a BlueRigger HDMI cable - the TV first senses it as a 1366*768 display out and sometimes mistakes it as a DVI! (it says so when the screen is booting up)

I think this is an issue with the TV, rather than the Pi, i connect my MacBook thru HDMi and have to adjust display Res to 1080p thru System Preferences

Does any one know what the problem is? Why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/boot/config.txt` and try;

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

There's some official documentation about this [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_group).  Although you did not say what actually happens after "first senses it as..." my thinking is that if the display then declares that resolution via [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) then you may end up with the wrong thing, but this should force 1080p mode.

You probably also want:

```
disable_overscan=1
```